# how to sum iterated count, also moving from single queries to many and creating a table output

Tags: python, python-2.7, counting

I have a single file containing thousands of DNA sequences in fasta format and I need to 
count how many times 100 individual short sequences (motifs) occur in the larger file.  So far, I've been doing motif by motif, but I can't figure out how to get my output summed so that I don't have a column of thousands of values.  It would also be great to input all the motifs at once and get a table back.  I'm super new to coding and appreciate any feedback!
I have;

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for i in SeqIO.parse(f,'fasta'):
   print i.seq.count('motif')
```

I was thinking I don't really need Biopython for this as the motifs won't hit in the 
sequence names.  So can I do an iterator that just reads line by line (...)?

my input is something like;

```
>fasta1
AACTGGGGTCCGTCGATAATATAGGATAG...
>fasta2
GCGCGTGATAGATATGATTAGCGGCGCAA...
```

etc

with motifs in a csv file like so;

```
ACCGAATTTAAA,AAATTATAAAA,GCCCTAAAAAG
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from Bio import SeqIO

sum = 0
for i in SeqIO.parse(f,'fasta'):
    sum += i.seq.count('motif')

print sum
```

If you want to count multiple files with file names like: fasta1, fasta2, ... fastaN

```
from Bio import SeqIO

sum_table

for k in range(N): 
    sum = 0   
    for i in SeqIO.parse(f,'fasta'+str(k+1)):
        sum += i.seq.count('motif')
    sum_table.append(sum)

print sum_table
```

You can do this without the library of course. But with the library in hand, why bother reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

If you rule out parsing, you'll have to options: either process the file line by line or read it as a whole first. Both approaches may have serious downsides:

if you read and count line by line, you'll not detect motifs intercepted with line breaks;

if you read it at once in a string and delete all newline characters (`\n`), you can run out of memory depending on the size of your file and available RAM.

Either way, assuming you have read your motif sequences from csv:

```
#let's say `motifs` is a list of motif sequences
counts = [0] * len(motifs)
for s in SeqIO.parse(f,'fasta'):
    for i, motif in enumerate(motifs):
        counts[i] += s.seq.count(motif)
```